Error in check balance and make transaction web wallet Stellar
function checkBalance() {
    const publicKey = document.getElementById('publicKey').value.trim();
    const balanceInfoElement = document.getElementById('balance-info');
    console.log('Checking balance for public key:', publicKey);

    if (!publicKey) {
        balanceInfoElement.innerHTML = '<p>Please enter a public key.</p>';
        return;
    }

    server.loadAccount(publicKey)
        .then(account => {
            console.log('Account loaded:', account);
            let balances = '<p>Balances for account: ' + publicKey + '</p>';
            account.balances.forEach(balance => {
                balances += `<p>Type: ${balance.asset_type}, Balance: ${balance.balance}</p>`;
            });
            balanceInfoElement.innerHTML = balances;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error loading account:', error);
            if (error instanceof StellarSdk.NotFoundError) {
                balanceInfoElement.innerHTML = '<p>Account not found. Please check the public key and try again.</p>';
            } else {
                balanceInfoElement.innerHTML = '<p>Error loading account. Please try again later.</p>';
            }
        });
}


Trying to make a web wallet for stellar and a check balance page html i get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: StellarSdk.Server is not a constructor
My project is about creating a web wallet for stellar asset. I successfully make a create wallet using stellar-sdk.min.js. But when i try to create a page to check balance or make transaction, i get the up mencioned error.
Same for make transaction:
function makeTransaction() {
    const sourceSecretKey = document.getElementById('sourceSecretKey').value.trim();
    const destinationPublicKey = document.getElementById('destinationPublicKey').value.trim();
    const amount = document.getElementById('amount').value.trim();
    const transactionInfoElement = document.getElementById('transaction-info');

    console.log('Making transaction from', sourceSecretKey, 'to', destinationPublicKey, 'amount', amount);

    if (!sourceSecretKey || !destinationPublicKey || !amount) {
        transactionInfoElement.innerHTML = '<p>Please fill in all fields.</p>';
        return;
    }

    const sourceKeypair = StellarSdk.Keypair.fromSecret(sourceSecretKey);

    server.loadAccount(destinationPublicKey)
        .catch(function (error) {
            throw new Error('The destination account does not exist!');
        })
        .then(() => server.loadAccount(sourceKeypair.publicKey()))
        .then((sourceAccount) => {
            const transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(sourceAccount, {
                fee: StellarSdk.BASE_FEE,
                networkPassphrase: StellarSdk.Networks.TESTNET
            })
                .addOperation(StellarSdk.Operation.payment({
                    destination: destinationPublicKey,
                    asset: StellarSdk.Asset.native(),
                    amount: amount
                }))
                .setTimeout(30)
                .build();

            transaction.sign(sourceKeypair);
            console.log('Transaction built:', transaction);

            return server.submitTransaction(transaction);
        })
        .then((result) => {
            transactionInfoElement.innerHTML = '<p>Transaction successful!</p>';
            console.log('Success! Results:', result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            transactionInfoElement.innerHTML = '<p>Transaction failed!</p>';
            console.error('Something went wrong!', error);
        });
}

